# Run Python function from html in flask with arguments

Tags: python, mysql, flask

So I have a project I'm working on, and I have a few textarea input boxes. I want to run a function in my main.py file, f.createHomework(c, m, e, ss, s, b, a, p, misc), with eveything after the c being inputs from textinput boxes in my index.html eith the same name

I have all my code attatched. Im a complete novice when it comes to html, flask, and js, so pardon my horrible organization and suboptimal code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Daily Homework</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="static/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  </head>
  <body style="background-color:rgb(104, 200, 255);">

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function expandContract() {
        const el = document.getElementById("inputLabel");
        el.classList.toggle('expanded');
      }

    </script>

    <style type="text/css">

      @font-face {
          font-family: "ArialRound";
          src: url('static/ArialRound.ttf') format("truetype");
      }

      h1 { 
          font-family: "ArialRound", Verdana, Tahoma;
          text-align: center;
          font-weight: bold;
      }

      #rcorners {
        border-radius: 15px;
        background-color: #00F3FF;
        border: 5px solid #0023FF;
        width: 350px;
        height: 50px;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 15px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      #entries {
        text-align: left;
        font-family: "ArialRound", Verdana, Tahoma;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 13px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      #inputButton {
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: #b9d7ff;
        border: 6px solid #edefff;
        width: 450px;
        font-family: "ArialRound", Verdana, Tahoma;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      #inputButton2 {
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: #b9d7ff;
        border: 4px solid #3f55ff;
        width: 450px;
        height: 50px;
        font-family: "ArialRound", Verdana, Tahoma;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      #ela {
        background-color: #ee98ff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px solid #ff00f2;
      }

      #math {
        background-color: rgb(255, 92, 114);
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px solid #ff0000;
      }

      #science {
        background-color: rgb(130, 255, 172);
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px solid #02df0d;
      }

      #socialStudies {
        background-color: rgb(255, 254, 183);
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px solid #eeff00;
      }

      #band {
        background-color: rgb(255, 133, 249);
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px solid #9900ff;
      }

      #advisory {
        background-color: rgb(81, 171, 255);
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px solid #0011ff;
      }

      #pe {
        background-color: #fff2cd;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px solid #aa7400;
      }

      #mis {
        background-color: #ffd885;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px solid #ffae00;
      }

      #inputLabel {
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
        transform: translateY(-110%);
        transition: transform 0.5s;
        width: 450px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: #b9d7ff;
        border: 6px solid #edefff;
        overflow: hidden; 
      }

      #inputLabel.expanded {
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: #b9d7ff;
        border: 6px solid #edefff;
        width: 450px;
        font-family: "ArialRound", Verdana, Tahoma;
        font-weight: bold;
        transform: translateY(0%);
      }

      #center {
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
      }

      #expandContainer {
        overflow: hidden;
      }

    </style>


    <h2 id="entries">{{ var1 }} Entries</h2>
    <h1 id="rcorners">Daily Homework</h1><br><br>
    <div id="center">

      <button id="inputButton" onclick="expandContract()">

        <h3>Click Here To Add New Entry</h3>
  
      </button>

    </div>

    <br>


    <div id="expandContainer">
      <div id="inputLabel">

        <div id="ela">
          <h4>ELA:</h4>
          <textarea id="e" style="background-color: #afd3ff;" name="ela" cols="50" rows="3" maxlength="150"> </textarea>
        </div>

        <br>

        <div id="math">
          <h4>Math:</h4>
          <textarea id="m" style="background-color: #afd3ff;" name="math" cols="50" rows="3" maxlength="150"> </textarea>
        </div>

        <br>

        <div id="science">
          <h4>Science:</h4>
          <textarea id="s" style="background-color: #afd3ff;" name="science" cols="50" rows="3" maxlength="150"> </textarea>
        </div>

        <br>

        <div id="socialStudies">
          <h4>Social Studies:</h4>
          <textarea id="ss" style="background-color: #afd3ff;" name="socialStudies" cols="50" rows="3" maxlength="150"> </textarea>
        </div>

        <br>

        <div id="band">
          <h4>Band:</h4>
          <textarea id="b" style="background-color: #afd3ff;" name="band" cols="50" rows="3" maxlength="150"> </textarea>
        </div>

        <br>

        <div id="advisory">
          <h4>Advisory:</h4>
          <textarea id="a" style="background-color: #afd3ff;" name="advisory" cols="50" rows="3" maxlength="150"> </textarea>
        </div>

        <br>

        <div id="pe">
          <h4>PE:</h4>
          <textarea id="p" style="background-color: #afd3ff;" name="pe" cols="50" rows="3" maxlength="150"> </textarea>
        </div>

        <br>

        <div id="mis">
          <h4>Miscellaneous:</h4>
          <textarea id="misc" style="background-color: #afd3ff;" name="mis" cols="50" rows="3" maxlength="150"> </textarea>
        </div>

        <br>

        <input id="inputButton2" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submit()">

      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

```
import mysql.connector
import functions as f
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from datetime import datetime
from markupsafe import escape

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host ="localhost",
    user ="Sebastian",
    passwd ="tiger0303",
    database="homework"
)

c = db.cursor()

app = Flask(__name__)

#c.execute("CREATE TABLE DailyHomework (date datetime, ELA VARCHAR(150), Math VARCHAR(150), Science VARCHAR(150), SocialStudies VARCHAR(150), Band VARCHAR(150), Advisory VARCHAR(150), PE VARCHAR(150), Misc VARCHAR(150) ID int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT)")

#c.execute("INSERT INTO DailyHomework (date, Misc) VALUES (%s,%s)", (datetime.now(), "Testing 12"))

#f.createHomework(c, " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "Gather Supplies")

db.commit()



@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('index.html', var1=f.countDays(c))
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

```
from datetime import datetime

def createHomework(cursor, m, e, ss, s, b, a, p, misc):
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO DailyHomework (date, ELA, Math, Science, SocialStudies, Band, Advisory, PE, Misc) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (datetime.now(), m,e,ss,s,b,a,p,misc))

def editELA(cursor, e, id):
    cursor.execute("UPDATE DailyHomework SET ELA = %s WHERE ID = %s", (e, id))

def editMath(cursor, m, id):
    cursor.execute("UPDATE DailyHomework SET Math = %s WHERE ID = %s", (m, id))

def editScience(cursor, s, id):
    cursor.execute("UPDATE DailyHomework SET Science = %s WHERE ID = %s", (s, id))

def editSocialStudies(cursor, ss, id):
    cursor.execute("UPDATE DailyHomework SET SocialStudies = %s WHERE ID = %s", (ss, id))

def editBand(cursor, b, id):
    cursor.execute("UPDATE DailyHomework SET Band = %s WHERE ID = %s", (b, id))

def editAdvisory(cursor, a, id):
    cursor.execute("UPDATE DailyHomework SET Advisory = %s WHERE ID = %s", (a, id))

def editPE(cursor, p, id):
    cursor.execute("UPDATE DailyHomework SET PE = %s WHERE ID = %s", (p, id))

def editMisc(cursor, misc, id):
    cursor.execute("UPDATE DailyHomework SET Misc = %s WHERE ID = %s", (misc, id))

def countDays(cursor):
    cursor.execute("SELECT ID FROM DailyHomework")
    id = [i for i in cursor]
    return(id[-1][0])

def getTable(cursor):
    cursor.execute("SELECT FROM DailyHomework")
    tbl = [i for i in cursor]
    return tbl
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn how HTML forms work and how to process them in Flask. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow isn't a tutorial site (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).